# Array search where each element contains long string

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying the following:

```
 $os = array("Helo how are you");

if (in_array("you", $os)) {
  echo "FOUND!!";
 }
```

I am trying to search for a word, but its not displaying anything. I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: You have to loop through the array and check strings with `strpos` function. Also `in_array` matches for whole string not substring.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
foreach ($os as $item) {
    if (strpos($item, 'you') !== false) {
        echo "FOUND!!";
        break;
    }
}
```

Or:

```
if (strpos(implode('', $os), 'you') !== false) {
    echo "FOUND!!";
}
```

Or:

```
if (preg_grep('/you/', $os)) {
    echo "FOUND!!";
}
```

Comment: First one is good while second isn't (imagine array `['y', 'ou']`)

Comment: @AlmaDo it's a boundary case. What about third one ? ;-)

Comment: Third one wasn't there while I was writing my comment :p I like `preg_grep()` - however, strings search with `strpos()` will be faster (but I doubt that difference will be noticeable in ordinary case)

Answer (score 0):

Try like,

```
$os = array("Helo how are you");
if (strpos($os[0],'are') !== false) {
    echo 'true';
}
```

Comment: What if array contains more than `0` index?

Comment: Thank u all !. If i want to print the index number would array_search work ?

Comment: array_search, will work fine but if your array has duplicate values like "hello how are you hello" then it will return index number of first "hello" and it is at index 0 it will not search further in the array for hello.

Comment: one failure of above described code is, on matching "Hel" instead of are it will return true as well.

Comment: if i want to search in an array with duplicate values like "array("hello how are you", "hello my name is")", and i try array_search for "hello", would it return 0,1 ? I have tried looping but its not dsiplaying